# How Would I Make an Object Curve With Vector3.MoveTowards Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make an object curve a little and not just move straight to the destination how would I do that with `Vector3.MoveTowards`?

Right now I only have this object moving towards another object called "gotocoin"; it just moves straight any help is appreciated thank you!

```
void Update()
{
    if (going == true)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, gotocoin.transform.position, 3 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you draw what you want to achieve?

Comment: You can use a [Bezier Curve](https://www.habrador.com/tutorials/interpolation/2-bezier-curve/). It's quite common for drawing a curved projectiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [Bezier Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) to solve your problem. I have written a simple code to demonstrate. It first calculates all the points between an initial position and the target position and then moves the object, which the script is attached to, to each of them. Changing control1 and control2 will change the shape of the curve. The Gizmos method is for debugging and can be removed.

```
[SerializeField] private Transform target;//the destination
[SerializeField] private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(4.58f, 4.52f, 0);//determines arch of the curve

private const float DistanceToTarget = 1;

private Vector3 _initialPosition;
private List<Vector3> _allPositions;
private int _counter;

private void Start()
{
    _initialPosition = transform.position;
    _allPositions = new List<Vector3>(100);

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var newPosition = CubicCurve(_initialPosition, _initialPosition + offset, _initialPosition + offset,
            target.position, (float)i / 100);
        _allPositions.Add(newPosition);
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if (_counter < _allPositions.Count)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _allPositions[_counter], Time.deltaTime);
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _allPositions[_counter]) < DistanceToTarget) _counter++;
    }
}

private Vector3 CubicCurve(Vector3 start, Vector3 control1, Vector3 control2, Vector3 end, float t)
{
    return (((-start + 3 * (control1 - control2) + end) * t + (3 * (start + control2) - 6 * control1)) * t +
            3 * (control1 - start)) * t + start;
}

//since _initialPosition is set on start, the drawn curve is from (0,0,0) if the code is not executed
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var newPosition = CubicCurve(_initialPosition, _initialPosition + offset, _initialPosition + offset,
            target.position, (float)i / 100);
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(newPosition, 1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I change the speed they move

Comment: Multiply Time.deltaTime of Vector3.MoveTowards by a factor

Comment: I have a question my player if he the target object changes position it does not curve towards it any more how can I fix this  the position my object might go high or down sometimes so I want to constant check the position

Comment: It occurs because the points of the curve are calculated in the Start method. You can create a method which runs the for loop in the Start. So whenever target moves, call this method and the points are updated. It's important to know that you can also run the code in the update method, let the start point be the player's position and the final point the target's position; however, the t parameter of the cubic curve will be 1 instantly, resulting in strange behavior (change the code and see). If u manage to find a better way to increase t, the curve is updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try using animation curves in unity's animation system. Hope this helps